# NullPointerException Parsing Jsoup

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, html-parsing, jsoup

I am getting a NullPointerException while using Jsoup to parse a website. The actual webpage which is parsed changes depending on user input. Essentially, sometimes there are images on the webpage and sometimes there are not.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.forbes.com/colleges/"+college+"/").get();
Elements photos = doc.select("div[id=photos]");
if(photos!=null){                   
    imgSrc1 = photos.select("li").select("img").first().attr("src");
    input1 = new java.net.URL(imgSrc1).openStream();
    bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input1);
    image1.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);

}else{
    buffer.append("No Pictures");
}
```

As of now, for the webpages which do have images, they show up properly. For those that do not have images, I get a NPE thrown. I tried preventing it by checking whether the id "photos" is present or not, but I am still getting the error.

Logcat:

```
07-30 16:24:43.497: E/AndroidRuntime(30847): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-30 16:24:43.497: E/AndroidRuntime(30847): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.collegeselector/com.collegeselector.CollegeInfo}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-30 16:24:43.497: E/AndroidRuntime(30847):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
07-30 16:24:43.497: E/AndroidRuntime(30847):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-30 16:24:43.497: E/AndroidRuntime(30847):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-30 16:24:43.497: E/AndroidRuntime(30847):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-30 16:24:43.497: E/AndroidRuntime(30847):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-30 16:24:43.497: E/AndroidRuntime(30847):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-30 16:24:43.497: E/AndroidRuntime(30847):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
07-30 16:24:43.497: E/AndroidRuntime(30847):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 16:24:43.497: E/AndroidRuntime(30847):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-30 16:24:43.497: E/AndroidRuntime(30847):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-30 16:24:43.497: E/AndroidRuntime(30847):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-30 16:24:43.497: E/AndroidRuntime(30847):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-30 16:24:43.497: E/AndroidRuntime(30847): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-30 16:24:43.497: E/AndroidRuntime(30847):    at com.collegeselector.CollegeInfo.onCreate(CollegeInfo.java:92)
07-30 16:24:43.497: E/AndroidRuntime(30847):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-30 16:24:43.497: E/AndroidRuntime(30847):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-30 16:24:43.497: E/AndroidRuntime(30847):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
07-30 16:24:43.497: E/AndroidRuntime(30847):    ... 11 more
```

What should I do to fix this?

Sample links:
http://www.forbes.com/colleges/cornell-university/ does NOT have the photos
http://www.forbes.com/colleges/columbia-university-in-the-city-of-new-york/ does have the photos

Comment: Are you sure the `<div id="photos">` is actually gone if there are no photos? It sounds like it still exists in html it's just empty. Likely you'll need to unchain the calls to `photos.select("li").select("img").first().attr("src");` and check if each one has non-null `Elements`

Comment: can you give a sample of college string that you are sending in jsoup.connect method?

Comment: @dymmeh No. In the link http://www.forbes.com/colleges/columbia-university-in-the-city-of-new-york/ there is <div id="photos">. But in the link www.forbes.com/colleges/cornell-university/ that is not even present.

Comment: @RJadhav I added a few sample links in the question. Thanks for the quick response

Comment: are you still getting npe with valid college links which have div id=photos?

Comment: No only for those without div id=photos

Comment: @RainbowJeremy What's `buffer` in your else statement? are you sure thats not null?

Comment: whats line number 92?

Comment: @dymmeh buffer is not null. It is a string builder with other data in it

Comment: @RJadhav line 92 is imgSrc1 = photos.select("li") and so on

Comment: @RainbowJeremy please attend ALL your questions and don't just create new ones! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25025279/android-jsoup-nullpointerexception-when-parsing-images

Comment: @Daniel B I changed the code since that question so although it was the same error, it was caused by different things.

Comment: Then you should comment that and provide an accurate answer and mark it as the answer, instead of leaving the question to just fade out. Read up on how StackOverflow works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if your photos element actually contains items

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.forbes.com/colleges/"+college+"/").get();
Elements photos = doc.select("div[id=photos]");
if(photos!=null && photos.size() > 0){                   
    imgSrc1 = photos.select("li").select("img").first().attr("src");
    input1 = new java.net.URL(imgSrc1).openStream();
    bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input1);
    image1.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
}else{
    buffer.append("No Pictures");
}
```

Notice the `photos.size() > 0` I added to your if statement. [`select(..)` statements in `Jsoup` will not return null if there are no elements. They will return an empty `Elements` list.](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#select(java.lang.String)) You just need to check the size of `photos`